# "Closed as off-topic" text is wrong on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, off-topic

When you tap to see the full closure reason for an off-topic question (e.g. [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4742/1908)) on the Android App (version 1.0.38), you see something like this:

[image]

> This question does not appear to be **about on-topic** within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with our API, we're investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with our API handling old questions that were closed using the default off-topic reason. It's been updated in the backend and is fixed in the app right now. Thanks!